# Send login headers python 2.7

Tags: python, json, api, iot

Hi I need to send login headers to sigfox. However they are always rejected or the code fails when I insert the auth variable in a call.

This is the code that does work but does reject.

```
print 'end of the dummy'
devices = requests.get("https://api.sigfox.com/v2/devices", auth=(API_USER, API_PWD)).json()
r = requests.get('https://api.sigfox.com/v2/devices', data=users, stream=True)
data = r.raw.read(r)
```

print(data)

And this is the code that fails.

```
credentials = b64encode(b"somebase64string:somebase64string").decode("ascii")
headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' %  credentials }


print 'end of the dummy'
devices = requests.get("https://api.sigfox.com/v2/devices", auth=(API_USER, API_PWD)).json() r = requests.get('https://api.sigfox.com/v2/devices', auth=credentials, data=users, stream=True) data = r.raw.read(r)


print(data)
```

The second code is less messy but stackoverflow works with idention. I think I need to pass the auth with in the r variable but I cannot figure out how I do that correctly. I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is one of the two:

1. you need to do a POST request instead of GET, since i see that you should send data in body and not as a params in the query.
2. you should use GET api in a proper way : `requests.get(url, params=None, **kwargs)`

this is the function signature from developer interface. so you should replace 
`r = requests.get('https://api.sigfox.com/v2/devices', data=users, stream=True)`
with 
`r = requests.get('https://api.sigfox.com/v2/devices', params=users, stream=True)`

but i strongly think it should be a POST request and not GET.

Comment: devices = requests.get("https://api.sigfox.com/v2/devices", auth=(API_USER, API_PWD)).json()
r = requests.post('https://api.sigfox.com/v2/devices', params=users, stream=True)
data = r.raw.read(r)


print(data) 

Still gives me 

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /api/v2/devices. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

I also thought it should be post. but the documentation says get.

Comment: if it is GET then you should use `params` and not `data` in your request

Comment: I did it looks like an issue on sigfox side, it has been an issue for more people over a year. Some obscure solution with curl were given, they worked for some time but now don't seem to anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode userid and password.

```
encodedUname = urllib.quote_plus(userName)
encodedPwd = urllib.quote_plus(password)
http://{encodedUname}:{encodedPwd}@{url}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specefic with an example?

Comment: Following link have example with both Using requests and urllib
https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-make-an-API-call-with-basic-HTTP-authentication-using-Python

Comment: Thx sadly ddidn't work. I used the latest example 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\devicetypes.py", line 171, in <module>
    data = r.raw.read(r)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 442, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 573, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 643, in _read_chunked
    amt -= chunk_left